# InfoPath Forms Services, Manage form templates error file not found

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath-forms-services

Im using Sharepoint 2010 and when i tried to go to Central Administration -> General Application Settings -> Manage form templates (InfoPath Forms Services), the page shows error , file not found, Troubleshoot issue with Microsoft Sharepoint Foundation. Correlation ID:xxxxxxxx.

[i use this instructions for the services activation](http://www.sharepointassist.com/2010/06/15/wheres-infopath-forms-services-in-sharepoint-2010/)

What should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem, Infopath form services is an enterprise feature....even sharepoint let you "activate" the feature. if you dont have a the enterprise version of sharepoint you will face this problem....

If you have a sharepoint enterprise CAL key you can upgrade your installation and then everything will work. [see this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261946.aspx) , make sure you dont have any problem with the timer service when you do this.

This is the list of some of the Enterprise services of SP:
Excel Services
Access Services
InfoPath Form Services
Visio Services and more...

I Hope this help you....

I have to admit that was my mistake to try to activate and use a enterprise feature in a standard installation, but sharepoint should have given a more meaningful message ... when trying to activate or when i click in the links.

let me know if this work for you.

ps: sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue and have had it for a while.  I have spent a lot of time seeking a solution.  My best guess is that one of the referenced files or namespaces in the files are invalid since it appears the referenced file does exist.  Maybe it is possible to debug the file using VS and ID the missing file?

Comment: FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.]  Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.ApplicationPages.AdminPageBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +386   Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.ApplicationPages.GridViewPageBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +16
Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.ApplicationPages.ManageFormTemplatesPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +18
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428

Comment: I also used the instructions used by the prior post.

Comment: Thanks, Dr. J.  You rock.  That fixed my problem.  I wish they could just code into the system the simple message: "Feature only available with Enterprise CAL."